# Where does the ending of Monarch Season 1 fit into the Monsterverse?

Tags: chronology, monsterverse, monarch-legacy-of-monsters

Season 1 of the Apple TV series *Monarch: Legacy of Monsters*, taking place in Legendary’s MonsterVerse, just got over.  The Season 1 finale ends with Keiko Randa, Cate Randa, and May Randa returning from the Hollow Earth, with two years having passed on the surface in the meantime.  They end up in Skull Island, where the APEX corporation now has a research station.

My question is, when does this occur in the timeline of the MonsterVerse?  For most of the series, the present-day events occur in 2015, one year after the 2014 *Godzilla* movie.  So two years later would be 2017, before the movie *Godzilla: King of the Monsters* which takes place in 2019.  Yet in *Godzilla: King of the Monsters*, it’s the organization MONARCH that’s in control of Skull Island, not the APEX Corporation, and in *Godzilla vs. Kong* APEX needs to get MONARCH’s permission to take Kong out of Skull Island and into the Hollow Earth.

So does control of Skull Island shift over time, or do MONARCH and APEX both have research outposts on Skull Island side by side, or what?

Comment: Right now, we don't know. Guess we'll have to wait for Season 2

Comment: @Paulie_D But what is it that we don’t know?  Is it at least clear that we’re before Godzilla King of the Monsters?  And what do we know of the relationship between Monarch and Apex based on Godzilla vs. Kong?

Comment: I refer to your question(s) at the end. We know little other than that they *do* have a relationship. APEX is, at least it's implied, funding Monarch but other than that we know practically nothing. This show is, kinda, a retcon of the movies timeline and so adds new stories weaved inside the movie chronology.

Comment: Is that implied?  I thought Monarch just get government funding.

Comment: No, the military cancelled their funding during the season.

Comment: That was in a flashback from the 1960’s.  The history of Monarch is a repeated history of the government threatening to pull or pulling their funding followed by restoring it.  We see in Kong: Skull Island that in the 1970’s, Monarch is still receiving government funding.